# Display ArrayList (EJB session + Servlet + JSP, no JDBC)

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, ejb

I've search on stack and on the internet and I haven't find the anwser at my problem.

I try to display an ArrayList from ejb to a jsp page by a servlet. I use mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin and not jdbc. I succeed in getting data from the database but the servlet is unable to send this ArrayList to the jsp page. Can you help? I've tried many checks and it seems like the problem is when I get the arraylist in servlet.. I probably badly call it..

Here my code :

accessBean :

```
public class accessBean implements accesCatalogueBeanRemote,     accesCatalogueBeanLocal {
public List getLivresList() {
        String flightQuery = "SELECT p FROM produit p"; 
        Query q = em.createQuery(flightQuery); 
        List existing = q.getResultList();          
        return existing;
    }

}
```

My servlet :

```
@WebServlet("/servlet")
public class servlet_produit extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                List list = null;

                //Connexion JNDI (annuaire pour localiser l'EJB)
                try{
                final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
                jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
                final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
                final String appName = "BktEAR";
                final String moduleName = "Commands";

                final String beanName = "JNDI";
                final String viewClassName = accesCatalogueBeanRemote.class.getName();
                accesCatalogueBeanRemote remote = (accesCatalogueBeanRemote)
                context.lookup("ejb:"+appName+"/"+moduleName+"/"+
                beanName+"!"+viewClassName);
                list = remote.getLivresList();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
                session.setAttribute("books", list);
                response.sendRedirect("product.jsp");
    }
}
```

And the place I call the servlet in my jsp page :

```
<c:forEach items="${books}" var="list">
    <tr>
        <td>ok : ${list.id}</td>
        <td><c:out value="${list.name}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${list.description}" /></td>
        <td><fmt:formatNumber value="${list.price}" type="currency" /></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Sorry : the first sentence is missing here. Sure, I've beginning by : 'Hello everybody' :)

Answer (score 1):

You are putting data into your session in this line

```
session.setAttribute("books", list);
```

So you should retrieve them in jsp from session. You can access session in jsp by using `${sessionScope.books}`.

This will helps you:

```
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.books}" var="list">
    <tr>
        <td>ok : ${list.id}</td>
        <td><c:out value="${list.name}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${list.description}" /></td>
        <td><fmt:formatNumber value="${list.price}" type="currency" /></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks but it do not work better. I think I just badly manage the arraylist in the servlet. I see the error : 'WFLYEJB0054: Failed to marshal EJB parameters' but it doesn't make sens for me..

Comment: @RobCime did you debug `list = remote.getLivresList();` this line and the list was ok?

Comment: I precisely think this is specifically this line that is problematic but I can’t resolve it..

Comment: @RobCime for testing purpose try too load all your data directly in your servlet. I mean use `Query q = em.createQuery(flightQuery); ` in your servlet and `session.setAttribute("books", q.getResultList());`

Comment: Thanks Spara. I have make this way and it works! not best but ok!